# How can i remove backstack "\" icon remove in inner json

Tags: java, android, json

I create one json and i try to remove backstack icon "\" from my json.

```
{"Brand":"Assemble Computer","Issue with device":"Power Code\/VGA","Problem in":"{\"0\":\"HDD\",\"1\":\"SSD\",\"2\":\"DVD writer\",\"3\":\"Keyboard Mouse\",\"4\":\"Monitor\"}","Model":"dddff"}
```

in this json i try to remove "\" in **Problem in** key How can i do that?

Comment: are you trying to remove the \ in all of the json or only in one part of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Using regex and replace maybe?

```
final String regex = "\\\\\\\"";

String originalJson = ... (your json);
String newJson = originalJson.replaceAll(regex, "\"");
```

This will replace all escaped quoataions with regular ones...